# Getting the output in a List format in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a following Python code: (from the Introduction to Machine Learning with Python book and 'http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.split')

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
for n_splits in [2, 3, 5]:    
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=False, random_state=0)
    X, y = iris.data, iris.target
    for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]    
        logreg_fit = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
        logreg_scores = logreg_fit.score(X_test, y_test)
        print('{}-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: {:.3f}'.format(
            n_splits, logreg_scores))
```

The output of this is:

```
2-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.947
2-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.947
3-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.961
3-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.922
3-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.958
5-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 1.000
5-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.967
5-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.933
5-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 0.900
5-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: 1.000
```

---

I would like to get output in the list form for each fold, i.e.
like this:

```
2-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: [ 0.947  0.947]
3-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: [ 0.961  0.922 0.958]
5-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: [ 1.000 0.967 0.933 0.900 1.000]
```

---

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This isn't just a Python question. It's about what the score() function returns, and making the effort to look there. I found this page that says the score is the mean accuracy, a single value, not a list. Read the scikit documentation to find what you want, and if you can't post a question about that package rather than Python in general.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks Chris and KyleKnoepfel for your sincere help. The solution provided by Sheshnath below answers my question perfectly and I am able to get the necessary output in the list form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, it's basically storing the results in a list and then printing it once the inner loop is completed.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
for n_splits in [2, 3, 5]:    
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=False, random_state=0)
    X, y = iris.data, iris.target
    res = []
    for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]    
        logreg_fit = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
        logreg_scores = logreg_fit.score(X_test, y_test)
        res.append(logreg_scores)
     print('{}-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: {}'.format(
        n_splits, res))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It works! The only thing I would like to edit in your code is that {:.3f} should be changed to { } (without the floating point decimal option) as using {:.3f} gives me the 'TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__' The fault is mine as I had included it in my above code. I just wanted to clarify it. In any case, thank you so much for simple and elegant solution!

Comment: Glad it helped and thanks for pointing the typo updated, accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way of doing it within the format list, but here is an alternative:

```
    print('{}-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: {}'.format(
        n_splits, ["{:.3f"}.format(member) for member in logreg_scores] ))
```

This will create a new list of strings where each member is a string of a 3dp float.

You could make it easier to read by moving it up into the line above:

```
    formatted_logreg_scores = ["{:.3f"}.format(member) for member in logreg_scores] 
    print('{}-fold STRATIFIED Cross-validation scores: {}'.format(
           n_splits, formatted_logreg_scores))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, running your code gives me the following error: 'TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable' [as stated above, I had removed :.3f inside { }  before running your code (it was my mistake that I had it there to begin with)].

Comment: Ah it seems that your `logreg_scores` is not a list of floats but a single float. You'll need to find the correct variable to give you a list of floats and then you can do my recommendation. Best of luck :)

Comment: Yes, I shall have to figure out a way to make that happen. Nevertheless, thank you again for your help.